# find elements with same charateristics

Tags: mysql, sql, select, relational-division

Supposing I have a table where a material has asignments of different characteristics. A material can have one or more charateristics. Then I would like to find to a certain material similar materials, that means at least 2 characteristics should match. In this example I should find material C when I compare with A and D should find B. Is there any solution in SQL?

```
material    | character
----------------------  
A           | 2
A           | 5
B           | 1
B           | 3
B           | 4
C           | 2
C           | 5
D           | 3
D           | 1
```

Comment: So you're giving a specific material as input? Or you want to return all pairs of materials that share a characteristic? Also have you tried anything?

Comment: SELECT x.m FROM x JOIN y ON y.m <> x.m AND y.c = x.c WHERE y.m = z GROUP BY x.m HAVING COUNT(*) >=2

Answer (score 3):

This is an Entity-Attribute-Value table, and it notoriously painful to search.  *(In this case, the `value` is implied as being `TRUE` for `has this attribute`.)*

It involves comparing everything against everything, grouping the results, and checking if the groups match.  Virtually no use of indexes or intelligence of any kind.

```
SELECT
  material_a.material   AS material_a,
  material_b.material   AS material_b
FROM
  material    AS material_a
LEFT JOIN
  material    AS material_b
    ON  material_a.character  = material_b.character
    AND material_a.material  <> material_b.material
GROUP BY
  material_a.material,
  material_b.material
HAVING
  0 = MAX(CASE WHEN material_b.character IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

This gives every material_b that has *all* of the characteristics that material_a has.
- The HAVING clause will check that every `0` of material a's characteristics are missing from material b.

Changing to an `INNER JOIN` and changing the `HAVING CLAUSE` will get the `share at least two materials`.

```
SELECT
  material_a.material   AS material_a,
  material_b.material   AS material_b
FROM
  material    AS material_a
INNER JOIN
  material    AS material_b
    ON  material_a.character  = material_b.character
    AND material_a.material  <> material_b.material
GROUP BY
  material_a.material,
  material_b.material
HAVING
  COUNT(*) >= 2
```

Either way, you still are joining the whole table against the whole table, then filtering out the failures.  With 100 materials, that's 9,900 material-material comparison.  Imagine when you have 1000 materials and have 999,000 comparisons.  Or 1million materials...

Comment: I think you're overthinking this one.

Comment: @Strawberry - Probably.  Do you have a particular aspect of "over thinking" that you mean?

Comment: Will this return revesered duplicated? i.e. `A-B B-A`

Comment: @OGHaza - Yep.  In the second query that warrants changing the join to `AND material_a.material  < material_b.material` - to ensure you only check `A vs B` but not `B vs A`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like the following grouped table to determine all items with more than 2 similar characteristics

```
SELECT
    material = t1.material
    , similarMaterial = t2.material
FROM
    tableName t1
    INNER JOIN tableName t2 ON t1.character = t2.character AND NOT(t1.material = t2.material)
GROUP BY material
HAVING 
    COUNT(*) >= 2
```

Answer (score 0):

This would give you the results based on a material input:

```
SELECT b.material
FROM table1 a
INNER JOIN table1 b 
  ON a.character = b.character AND a.material <> b.material
WHERE a.material = 'A'  -- Your input
GROUP BY b.material
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dd45f/2)</kbd>

Or do this to give you the pairs:

```
SELECT a.material as LEFT_MATERIAL ,b.material AS RIGHT_MATERIAL
FROM table1 a
INNER JOIN table1 b ON a.character = b.character AND a.material <> b.material
GROUP BY a.material,b.material
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dd45f/8)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can find all paired of similar materials with SQL similar to this:

```
SELECT c1.material, c2.material, COUNT(*) as characterCount
FROM charateristics c1
    CROSS JOIN charateristics c2
WHERE c1.material > c2.material AND c1.character = c2.character
GROUP BY c1.material, c2.material
HAVING characterCount >= 2;
```